# Marriage visitor visa for US citizens with children

Tags: visa, us-citizens, uk-visa, marriage, uk-visitor-visa

Obviously I can come in and out of UK as I have done so in the last 7 years. I have entered UK for multiple times and my longest stay was a month. I and my partner would like to get married and since we want to do it right by abiding immigration rules, we are looking at marriage visitor visa since I don’t plan to stay in UK. My question is, I have two children who are US citizens, do I apply for them? If so, in what type of visa? They will be coming with me for the wedding and I’m not sure if they can just enter the UK like how we have been doing without a visa requirement. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since this question is about a short-term stay in the UK, it might fit better at [Travel.SE].

Comment: But won’t we violate immigration law by just marrying with no visa? Won’t the registrar ask for it as well?

Comment: Yes, you need a marriage visitor visa to marry in the UK.  Nobody has suggested otherwise.  The marriage visitor visa is a short-term visa, so it is a more appropriate topic for the [Travel.SE] site than for this one, which concerns moving to another country for an extended period.

Answer (score 1):

Since your children would not be getting married, they can enter as visitors, as they have been doing.  Because they are not required to have visas to enter as visitors, you do not need to apply for visas for them.

Comment: I only have a pt job,saved $10k. My fiancé is British but isn’t working at the moment. We are planning to apply for marriage visitor visa since I don’t plan on living in the UK just as yet due to my chidlren’s Education and parental visits and he’s also not moving to the USA as he has children living in UK as well. We would like to plainly get married,we won’t be living together after. What is the chance of getting this visa? I have been to UK lots of time and the longest is 2 months when kids were off school. what kind of solid evedience they are looking for to get approved?

Comment: @ElleLim Nobody can predict your chance of getting the visa with any reliability.  If you want to ask about the best way to prepare an application, you can ask a new question.  As noted in a comment on your question, [Travel.SE] is a more appropriate site than this one to ask about visitor visas, including marriage visitor visas. There are already several questions there on the topic; you may want to have a look.  But it's probably easier to get married in the US if that's an option.